# taking the optimum route for memoization

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, memoization

I was asked to write a recursive function in python which takes some positive intger as an argument and print till it reaches 1 - it had to be created using memoization as per the question.

My approach is to take a `dictionary` and save every sub-call, example: if the integer passed intially is **5** and it is not found in the dictionary - the function should go till 1 and save a list `[1]` corresponding to key `1` and then save a list `[1,2]` corresponding to key `2`, similarly `[1,2,3,4,5]` corresponding to key `5`.

Is it a good approach or should I only save the value `[1,2,3,4,5]` corresponding to key `5` and quit the function?

Also, is it really memoization which I did? (I am new to this topic)

Comment: If you're really supposed to be doing both recursion and memoization, then when you call f(5), it should memoize the resulting value.  Of course, it's going to recursively call f(4), and its the call to f(4) that's going to be saving that value.  Each call only saves its own return value, and its up to recursion to take care of the rest.

Comment: I think I get your question, but can you show the function you wrote, just to be extra sure?

Comment: @SolarMike.  Google is your friend.

Comment: You can always time things and see what's beneficial and by how much. See the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) module.

Comment: @Solar: See Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization),

Comment: @Solar: Indeed. It's really easy to implement in Python via the `functools.cache` or `functools.lru_cache` decorators in the [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#module-functools) module.